# having a hard time displaying a key in a object array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

[image]

i wanted to print the encircle ones itself in the console but im having a hrd time accessing it. so if i want to access "Vignesh" having a comment of "good"  and assuming the result refers to the root of the tree, my code will be

```
 console.log(result["Vignesh"]["comments"][0]["A"]);
```

how do i access the key of the comment? the "A" , "B" and "C"? because ill put it in a for loop so that it will display all his/her comments.

initial code for displaying a name("Gokul", "kavin" etc) with all his comments.

```
 for(var key in result){ //key returns Gokul, Kavin etc
        for(var key2 in result[key].comments){    //key2 returns exm 0 1 2 in comments
           console.log(result[key]["comments"][key2]["A"].....);
        }
   }
```

Comment: why tag php though?

Comment: Please don't post code as images.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
for(var key in result){ //key returns Gokul, Kavin etc
    for(var key2 in result[key].comments){    //key2 returns exm 0 1 2 in comments
       var comment = result[key]["comments"][key2];
       console.log(comment[Object.keys(comments)[0]]);
    }
}
```

BTW, it's preferable for readability to use dot notation instead of square brackets where possible. So `result[key].comments` instead of `result[key]["comments"]`.

Comment: it gives me comments undefined

Comment: modified some of it and it works, giving me all the comments. but i wanted to display the A B C which is the key? how do i do that?

Comment: because that A B C is just a sample data but in with the correct data that will be replace by the name who reviewed and i will display it. im having a hard time :(

Comment: `Object.keys(comments)[0]` will show the A B C keys, and `comments[Object.keys(comments)[0]]` is for the values

Answer (score 0):

The key to get the property names of an object is to use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). If you have control of the backend I do suggest remodeling the comments structure to a more readable format like `comments: [{name: 'A' , text: 'good'}]`. With that been said, here is how you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the info you are looking for with current data model:

```js
var result = {
  Vignesh: {
    avgrating: 2.33,
    comments: [
      {A: "good"},
      {B: "Bad"},
      {B: "so good"},
    ]    
  }
}

for (var topLevelUser in result){
  if  (result.hasOwnProperty(topLevelUser) && result[topLevelUser].comments){
    console.log(topLevelUser);
    
    var comments = result[topLevelUser].comments;
    
    comments.forEach(function(comment){
      var subUser = Object.keys(comment)[0];
      var text = comment[subUser];
      
      console.log(subUser, '=>', text)
    });    
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this:

```
result["Vignesh"]["comments"][0].forEach(function(value,key){console.log('Comment '+key+': '+value+'; ')});
```

Comment: hii, why does it give me foreach is not a function?

Comment: `forEach` is not available in objects only in arrays.